# Как сделать горизонтальный scroll для editText?

Tags: java, android

Как сделать scroll как на [видео](https://youtu.be/OlqROPtCVwc). Есть такая разметка:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/editText3"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:maxLength="15"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:targetApi="o" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько способов. Например можно поместить ваше поле для ввода в другой макет:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/edit_text">
<EditText
   android:layout_width="120dp"
   android:layout_height="21dp"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_margin="6dp"
   android:background="#00000000"
   android:imeOptions="actionDone"
   android:maxLength="20"
   android:maxLines="1"
   android:paddingLeft="2dp"
   android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Либо поместить `Edittext` в `HorisontalScrollView` и настроить его таким образом:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
android:id="@+id/rlEmail"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scrollHorizontally="true" >
<EditText
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:ems="10"
  android:enabled="false"
  android:focusable="false"
  android:maxLines="1"
  android:singleLine="true"
  android:scrollHorizontally="true" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Можно настроить только поле для ввода и не помещать его в другие контейнеры:

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:maxLines="1"
```

Так же можно настроить программно из класса активности:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.some_edittext);
editText.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
editText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```